# Strange requests for gif image from stimulsoft

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, elmah, stimulsoft

I am using stimulsoft for reporting and also elmah for logging errors in my application.

Both works fine, but the problem is when i am open a form that stimul created, then elmah log some errors that says some controllers does not exist.

Those errors are logs because stimul request some strange gif images.

Here is a image from errors:

[image: errors]

How can i fix this errors?

Comment: What do the 'Details...' links show?

Comment: My research gives two possibilities... it's either a namespace issue (check your routes) or a plugin is borked (you could reinstall the theme locally and rebuild in VS).

Comment: I did the best i could and put this code `routes.IgnoreRoute("{*name}", new { name = @"\[(.*).gif\]" });` to ignore those request.

Answer (score 0):

There was such issue in the very old build of Stimulsoft Reports.
Upgrade to the latest build.